# issue saving / submitting a webform using selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, selenium

i am failing for several days now to save a form once i filled all fields. I can click on the save button, but nothing happens. The page remains as is, and does not show anything saved and no errors running the script.

Here is an extract of the  HTML of the website (It is an intranet website, so not accessible to the public) and extract of the  python code i got together.

I tested several different ways to submit (xx.click(), xx.submit(), execute_script () etc...) to no avail. I also tried to call the javascript instead of clicking on the button, but that did not work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Here HTML extract of the webpage:

```
<INPUT onclick=clearDirty();javascript:saveForm(); class=button type=button 
     value=Save>
```

- and here the Python script i am trying to use without success:

```
    saving = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//input[@value = "Save"]')
    saving.click()
```

I have also tested executing the JS through selenium. That throws a Traceback "undefined is not a constructor", my button does not get clicked or my form not saved:

```
Saving = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value = "Save"]')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Saving)
```

and then i tested this, thinking the JS maybe wanted to reload the page i was on and may want to "return" something. That throws a Traceback "undefined is not a constructor", my button does not get clicked or my form not saved:

```
nextpage = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].click();", Saving)
print ("NEXTPAGE:", nextpage, type(nextpage))
```

Comment: there is way too much code here, it's really hard to follow / understand where the issue is with what you're asking. You're saying the webdriver presses the save button, but then nothing happens? Have you tried debugging to that point and then trying to manually press the save button yourself instead when reaching that part? What is the result?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @PreciseMotion. I scrapped few liunes of the code, but left the "saveform" function and the table i am trying to save. I am using a headless PhantomJS browser, so i cannot click the button myself. However when opening the site in IE, i can see that it does a POST when i click on the save button. I suspect this does not happen when clicking on save in PhantomJS.

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for your question DebanJanB. I treid to edit the question. My issue is nothing happens when i click on the save button. The form should get saved and the data added to the table, but nothing happens. No errors, just nothing. I hope that helps.

Comment: @PreciseMotion One additional comment that may point to the issue: when trying to click on the "save" button manually in Chrome or Firefox, nothing happens either. That button only works when i use IE.

Comment: From where did you get this somehow crampy html code? Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) first, then see what to fix, plus no quoted attribute values. It lacks of closing tags. Also your save button must be of type "submit" to get the form post away.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 functions in the `onclick` attribute of your save button. The first one `clearDirty()` is not defined. This causes the js interpreter to stop immediately at this error and it does not continue on the second function `saveForm()`.

A short stub could work around quickly:
`function clearDirty() { }`.

I'd recommend to put your function definition `saveForm()` plus the `clearDirty()` stub between *script* tags, like this:

```
<script>
  function saveForm() {
    ...
  }

  function clearDirty() { }
</script>
```

If you do so, you should be able to see your `saveForm()` gets called. But there are other issues, see below.

As another test, you could even remove the function `clearDirty();` from your save Button's `onclick` attribute. Then you see the `saveForm()` function gets called properly.

The form gets submitted to the location stated by the action attribute. If there is no such attribute or its value is empty, it gets posted to itself. In your case the location will be: `OBS/financial_model_tp_labor_otc.htm`.

If you make use of an element's `submit` function with selenium, all form buttons are bypassed and the form itself gets submitted immediately by resolving the form's `action` attribute. This should work at any time, regardless of your button and js configuration. If not, there's really something wrong with your generated html.

I'd really suggest to use an html validator. The html source looks like coming from a very outdated M$ tool. There are plenty out in the net. I used the [W3C service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) as a first shot. Just point to your local html-File and press ***check***.

Beside language and character encoding issues, there are missing closing html tags reported right at the bottom by the tool.

And please double quote your attribute values, there are special characters in.

**edit**

I'll provide you a small sample. First create 2 html files as follows.

ta.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .bkon {
        background-color: darkgreen !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="font-family:helvetica;text-align:center">
    <div id="frmdiv" style="margin:2em;padding:2em;background-color:lightsalmon;border: solid grey .5em;border-radius:.5em">
      <p>
        Find the button below which gets the form posted away
      </p>
      <form action="succ.html" method="post">
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="clearDirty();btnclk()" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      function btnclk() {
        var dv = $("#frmdiv");
        if(! dv.hasClass("bkon")) {
          dv.addClass("bkon");
        }
        else {
          dv.removeClass("bkon");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

succ.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body style="font-family:helvetica">
    <div style="font-size:2em;background-color:lightgreen;text-align:center;margin-top:2em;padding:.5em;">
      <p>
        you got the form submitted successfully
      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
      <a href="ta.html">go back</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can have a selenium test like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///path/to/test/your/ta.html")
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value = "Save"]')
time.sleep(2)
btn.click()
time.sleep(2)
btn.submit()
```

In the test I use the form button in two ways. First by just calling the button's click function which is equivalent to a mouse click. Second by using its submit function.

I deliberately added your suspicious `clearDirty()` function in the button's `onclick` attribute to show you that selenium's click fails but the submit passes. Remove the `clearDirty()` function from the `onclick` attribute and you will see that even the click works by then, which is also testable by a manual mouse click.

Comment: Thanks @Woodz. This is an extensive answer that led me on many paths.
Excuse my asking : you mean to add the function in the <script> tag to the HTML I presume ? I do not have access to the HTML source code so cannot modify it or add tags to it. I have tried a few things and edited the post to reflect progress (?) made.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand where you are up to. You mix some selenium things into some test or automation intention for a very outdated site which isn't available to the world. It feels the tool which generates this awful html (which is also faulty, if you haven't forgot to put all information into you original question) had its time to live and there is really nothing to test with it any more.

Comment: I would suggest, to get a feeling how selenium plays on the web, make a simple static html form with one submit button which posts to another html file, like a success page with only static text. Open it in your browser and see manually, whether it works to your expectation. Not before this is all OK you can start fiddling with selenium. I might give you a sample soon...

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you with a sample. Please read my answer again completely, since I was wrong with the `submit` explanation of selenium. Btw. you recent question edit made it much more difficult to help you by so's folks since you are hiding important information